# Assign a timeout period for MySQL queries

Tags: linux, mysql, database

Is there a way to assign a timeout period for MySQL queries, and limit them to say 60 seconds? I know its possible to do this when using a scripting language (eg, PHP). But is it possible to set a configuration in MySQL directly to prevent long running queries (typically selects in my case) from taking out the server?

NOTE: Running Mandriva, DB is in MyISAM, and this is for SELECT queries only.

Comment: Are these select queries or insert/update/delete ones? If they are select queries only, you can setup a mysql slave and give your boss access to slave.

Comment: Select only. That is a possibility I have been considering as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution I typically do, if replication / slaves are not an option is this and you're trying to avoid long running report queries;

- Assess which slow running SELECT queries are repeatedly executed
- Turn the SELECT statements into report tables: CREATE TABLE report AS SELECT...
- And fill the report tables nightly or whatever the case may be with a CRON job and that SELECT statement.

In this case your boss would be getting the data a lot quicker in the new report table(s). You probably have a good solution figured out already, but this could still be useful. :)

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution is to use Percona Toolkit's [pt-kill](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.1/pt-kill.html) option. It has several options and in use by several people.

I would recommend to use slave server but it requires additional resources (server/instance). In this approach, your production server will be isolated and no damage will be done to the business even if your boss writes a worst query.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your response about queries type I can say the following:

If your boss is executing only select statement, you can consider installing and running [mysql replication](http://www.howtoforge.com/mysql_database_replication) and grant him access to the slave database server. This way your production (master) server will not be affected if he typed a very complicated and time-consuming query.

Answer (score 1):

Not by default, no.

However the Twitter team has released their work on MySQL which exactly implements this (from http://engineering.twitter.com/2012/04/mysql-at-twitter.html):

`- Reduce unnecessary work through improved server-side statement timeout support. This allows the server to proactively cancel queries that run longer than a millisecond-granularity timeout.`

See https://github.com/twitter/mysql/wiki/Statement-Timeout and https://github.com/twitter/mysql.

A more trivial solution is to run a cronjob every X minutes which searches for queries by your boss and kill them if they run longer than Y seconds.